# Large Random Graph is Surely Connected

Tags: probability, random-graphs

I'm trying to prove that for a random graph on $n$ vertices with edge-probability $p \in (0, 1)$ is almost surely connected as $n$ grows large. I've tried making an argument using the probability of having a component of size $< n/2$ or a path not existing between some vertices $u, v$ and using the union bound, but the probabilities don't quite work out. Could someone give me a hint in the right direction?

Edit: The model in question is starting with $n$ vertices, and having each edge appear independently with probability $p$.

Comment: You might want to specify exactly how the random graph is assembled. I *think* I know which one you are using, but I am not certain. Specifically I think you are using the version where you add a vertex and then, independently with probability $p$, connect it to each of the previous vertices.

Comment: I think that would be equivalent. My interpretation of the question was that given any positive $\epsilon$ we can always find an $n$ such that the probability of getting a disconnected graph is less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: Yes, but @Ian's point is that "random graph" is vague. To get a good answer to this question, you have to explain the process by which you are "randomly" choosing/constructing your graphs.

Comment: Use arguments in the original paper by Erdös and Renyi who proved this if $p > \frac{1}{n}$, which is asymptotically the case in your setup.

Comment: @HansEngler I would think that this depends on the model being the Erdos-Renyi model rather than the Gilbert model (see the first two paragraphs of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_graph#Random_graph_models ). I haven't read the paper, though, so I'm not certain.

Comment: The definition that I'm using is Gilbert's model, sorry for not specifying.